# Dúvida de lógica em Python com o uso de while

Tags: python-3.x

Encontrei esse código em uma aula da faculdade em que o loop continua rodando enquanto não for digitado zero, após digitar o número zero o loop é encerrado e ele mostra a média dos números digitados.

```
soma_total_numeros = 0
qtd_numero = 0
numero = 0

while True:
  numero = int(input('Digite um número:'))
  if numero<0:
    continue 
  if not numero:
    break
  soma_total_numeros += numero
  qtd_numero+= 1

media_numeros = soma_total_numeros/ qtd_numero 
print('Média dos valores digitados: {}'.format(media_numeros))
```

Minha duvida é com relação a este trecho em específico. Aqui está especificando para o loop continuar enquanto o número digitado for menor que zero, mas isso faria o programa encerrar e não continuar, certo?

```
if numero<0:
  continue
```

Comment: O que faz saltar fora do loop é o `if not numero:` pois aí é testado se o valor é zero (zero é igual a "falso", e "not falso" é "true"). O comando `break` faz sair do laço

Comment: O `if numero<0` é apenas para recusar números negativos -  não os insere na conta que soma os números. O continue faz com que o laço corrente chegue ao fim, retornando ao teste do while (ou seja, no teu caso, ao início do loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesse laço, o que está acontecendo é o seguinte: inicialmente o usuário digita um valor. Se esse valor for negativo (menor que zero), ele "volta" para o inicio do loop. O comando `continue` "termina" a execução corrente do loop sem executar nenhum dos comandos abaixo, ele volta ao teste do loop - no caso, True. Imagino que isso seja para excluir números negativos do cálculo.

Logo depois, ele testa se o número é zero no `if not numero:`. Parece estranho, mas para muitas linguagens de programação, zero é falso, e o teste "nega" o valor do número. Então, ali, ele vai entrar no `if` se o valor for zero apenas. Dentro do `if` tem o comando `break` - e é aí que ele salta fora do laço de execução e vai para o cálculo da média.

Os cálculos eu imagino que tu entendeste, certo? Basicamente ele soma os valores e vai contando o nº de valores digitados, depois, quando sai do laço, ele faz a média  e imprime.

Tá claro?

Comment: Agora consegui compreender, muito obrigado pela explicação detalhada, com certeza vai me ajudar a ter uma noção melhor das coisas daqui pra frente.